# How to prevent DatePickerDialog cutoff on low resolutions?

Tags: android, screen-size, datepickerdialog

I'm currently having a issue getting the `DatePickerDialog` calendar control to appear properly on lower resolution devices.

On months with more than 6 week rows the bottom row of the calendar is cut off. 
The below screenshots show an example for October missing its last two days on a Samsung XCover 3.

[image]
[image]

The `DatePickerDialog` is initialized like this:

```
 DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, handler, 2017, 9, 1);
 dialog.SetTitle("");
```

I'm not sure if this issue is Samsung XCover specific (its the only low resolution device I have) or if it occurs for all low resolution devices. Is there any way this cut off can be prevented?

Comment: I think this most probably Samsung specific device issue. Have try with some other low resolutions device instead Samsung ?

Comment: Manage to resolve this? Running into the same issue with this device

Comment: It seems to be XCover specific, but I have not found a solution yet.

Comment: Thought as much, surprised Samsung haven't been forced to push a fix for it